# Java "Could not find or load main class <Class Name>

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I have a lot of java classes in school. At the beginning of September, I re-formatted my laptop to Windows 10 (it was Windows 10 before as well).

- BEFORE re-formatting: Everything was running perfectly fine
- AFTER re-formatting: I installed jdk 8u101 x64 and NetBeans 8.2.(I was using Netbeans before as well and an older version of jdk, if I'm not wrong).

I open my project that I wrote on lab in my school, and when I press build and run it, it gives me the error:

```
Could not find or load main class <Class Name>
```

I tried to create a new project just to see if something is wrong with the code I took from school, but I got the same problem. Could you please help me solve the problem?

Comment: check your main method signature and i assume your class and file name are same because netbeans won't allow difference if class is public

Comment: I opened it in cmd i have a test project named "JavaApplication1" class name and Class name is exactly the same i run javac it compiles it perfectly fine BUT when i run java ClassName it throws me that error ....

Comment: you mean e.g `class Foo`  and `Foo.java` plus Foo should have `public static void main(String[] args)` method

Comment: my java files contains only theese: class JavaApplication1 { public static void main(String[] args){ }}

Comment: contains only these ?

Comment: I told you this is a test class. this is not my main project from school

Comment: dude obviously it won't run without main method signature , you can read about java basics to compile and run

Answer (score 0):

The java  command syntax

First of all, you need to understand the correct way to launch a program using the java (or javaw) command.

The normal syntax1 is this:

```
java [ <option> ... ] <class-name> [<argument> ...]
```

where  is a command line option (starting with a "-" character),  is a fully qualified Java class name, and  is an arbitrary command line argument that gets passed to your application.
1 - There is a second syntax for "executable" JAR files which I will describe at the bottom.

The fully qualified classname is conventionally written as you would in Java source code; e.g.

```
packagename.packagename2.packagename3.ClassName
```

However some versions of the java command allow you to use slashes instead of periods; e.g.

```
packagename/packagename2/packagename3/ClassName
```

which (confusingly) looks like a file pathname, but isn't one. Note that the term fully qualified classname is standard Java terminology ... not something I just made up to confuse you :-)

Here is an example of what a java command should look like:

```
java -Xmx100m com.acme.example.ListUsers fred joe bert
```

The above is going to cause the java command to do the following:

Search for the compiled version of the com.acme.example.ListUsers class.
Load the class.
Check that the class has a main method with signature + modifiers public static void main(String[]).
Call that method passing it the command line arguments ("fred", "joe", "bert") as a String[].
Reasons why Java cannot find the class

When you get the message "Could not find or load main class ...", that means that the first step has failed. The java command was not able to find the class. And indeed, the "..." in the message will be the fully qualified class name that java is looking for.

So why might it be unable to find the class? Basically, there are two main causes:

The first likely cause is that you may have provided the wrong class name. (Or ... the right class name, but in the wrong form.) Considering the example above, here a variety of wrong ways to specify the class name:

Example #1 - a simple class name:

java ListUser
When the class is declared in a package such as com.acme.example, then you must use the full classname including the package name in the java command; e.g.
java com.acme.example.ListUser
Example #2 - a filename or pathname rather than a class name:
java ListUser.class
java com/acme/example/ListUser.class
Example #3 - a class name with the casing incorrect:
java com.acme.example.listuser
Example #4 - a typo
java com.acme.example.mistuser
The second likely cause is that the class name is correct, but that the java command cannot find the class. To understand this, you need to understand the concept of the "classpath". This is explained well by the Oracle documentation:

The java command documentation
Setting the Classpath.
The Java Tutorial - PATH and CLASSPATH
So ... if you have specified the class name correctly, the next thing to check is that you have specified the classpath correctly:

Read the three documents linked above. (Yes ... READ them. It is important that a Java programmer understands at least the basics of how the Java classpath mechanisms works.)
Look at command line and / or the CLASSPATH environment variable that is in effect when you run the java command. Check that the directory names and JAR file names are correct.
If there are relative pathnames in the classpath, check that they resolve correctly ... from the current directory that is in effect when you run the java command.
Check that the class (mentioned in the error message) can be located on the effective classpath.
Additional Notes:

When you put a directory on the classpath, it notionally corresponds to the root of the qualified name space. Classes are located in the directory structure beneath that root, by mapping the fully qualified name to a pathname. So for example, if "/usr/local/acme/classes" is on the class path, then when the JVM looks for a class called com.acme.example.Foon, it will look for a ".class" file with this pathname:

```
/usr/local/acme/classes/com/acme/example/Foon.class
```

If you had put "/usr/local/acme/classes/com/acme/example" on the classpath, then the JVM wouldn't be able to find the class.
The classpath needs to include all of the other (non-system) classes that your application depends on. (The system classes are located automatically, and you rarely need to concern yourself with this.)
The java -jar  syntax

The alternative syntax used for "executable" JAR files is as follows:

```
java [ <option> ... ] -jar <jar-file-name> [<argument> ...]
```

e.g.

```
java -Xmx100m -jar /usr/local/acme-example/listuser.jar fred
```

In this case the name of the entry-point class (i.e. com.acme.example.ListUser) and the classpath are specified in the MANIFEST of the JAR file.

IDEs

A typical Java IDE has support for running Java applications in the IDE JVM itself or in a child JVM. These are generally immune from this particular exception, because the IDE uses its own mechanisms to construct the runtime classpath, identify the main class and create the java command line.

However it is still possible for this exception to occur, if you do things behind the back of the IDE to break things. For example, if you have previously set up an Application Launcher for your Java app in Eclipse, and you then moved the JAR file containing the "main" class to a different place in the file system without telling Eclipse, Eclipse would unwittingly launch the JVM with an incorrect classpath.

In short, if you get this problem in an IDE, check for things like stale IDE state, broken project references or broken launcher configurations.